# Android Java JSON Unhandled Exception

Tags: java, android

I have a method which needs to return a JSONObject:

```
public JSONObject getDayJson(Date date) {
   ...
   a few lines of code
   ...
   return new JSONObject("..");
}
```

However this gives me an error as I need to catch any exceptions which may occur as a result of instantiating the JSONObject:

```
public JSONObject getDayJson(Date date) {
  try { 
      ...
      a few lines of code
      ...
      return new JSONObject("..");
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // need a return statement here!
   }
}
```

This creates another error as in the catch block I am not returning the correct object type which is a JSONObject. If I do instantiate another JSONObject in the catch I need to nest another catch statement?!

Comment: or you can have you method declare the exception as thrown, and leave the calling object the handling of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better think what you want to do if an exception happens, but one option is to force a non exception calling constructor.

```
public JSONObject getDayJson(Date date) {
  try { 
      ...
      a few lines of code
      ...
      return new JSONObject("..");
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // doesn't throw another exception
      return new JSONObject(new HashMap());
   }

}
```